# How to get value through ajax by processing the acess rights via cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

The problem is: I have made a gallery lightbox like that of facebook which will load image in the left side and have some space for the content in the right side, now i have to load the content to be placed in the right side, but i want those comments by processing the access right, like: only such information will be displayed which the logged in user is allowed to view, now can i process the server side directly by using cookie? or I need to give the cookie variables along the request, then process? if so is `json` for me? Or there is something that will make my job much easier?

Comment: Yes, your server will get the cookies (and other HTTP headers) as usual when requested via ajax (not depending on the type of response); so you can use the standard authentication methods.

Comment: that means i can use `$_COOKIE` variable and do all the processing?

Comment: Yes, why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: i had tried to set the cookie via ajax once but it didn't worked so i thought ajax wont transfer cookie so can i also even set the cookie via ajax?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. [Show us](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13036874/edit) that code (both client- and serverside) that does not work.

Comment: now i have forgot where i did that, may be i missed something there, thanks!